# SQL Group By status

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am looking for a way to group data by status. I have this with a simple select, just for demonstration:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b862/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Projects ([ID] int, [Project] varchar(10));
INSERT INTO Projects ([ID], [Project])
VALUES
    (1, 'Admin'),
    (2, 'Accounts'),
    (3, 'Finance')
;

CREATE TABLE Tasks ([ID] int, [ProjectID] int, [Task] int, [Status] varchar(8));
INSERT INTO Tasks
    ([ID], [ProjectID], [Task], [Status])
VALUES
    (1, 1, '001', 'Open'),
    (2, 1, '002', 'Canceled'),
    (3, 1, '003', 'Canceled'),
    (4, 1, '004', 'Canceled'),
    (5, 2, '005', 'Rejected'),
    (6, 2, '006', 'Canceled'),
    (7, 2, '007', 'Canceled'),
    (8, 3, '008', 'Canceled'),
    (9, 3, '009', 'Canceled'),
    (10, 3, '010', 'Canceled'),
    (11, 3, '011', 'Canceled'),
    (12, 3, '0012', 'Rejected')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  Projects.Project,
  COUNT(Tasks.Status) AS Total
FROM
  Projects
  LEFT JOIN Tasks ON Projects.ID = Tasks.ProjectID
 GROUP BY
   Projects.Project
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b862/1/0)**:

```
|  Project | Total |
|----------|-------|
| Accounts |     3 |
|    Admin |     4 |
|  Finance |     5 |
```

But I am looking for a way to output this:

```
|  Project | Open | Canceled | Rejected |
|----------|------|----------|----------|
|    Admin |    1 |        3 |          |
| Accounts |      |        2 |        1 |
|  Finance |      |        4 |        1 |
```

The desired result groups the **Project** by **Tasks Status**. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Check the answers in this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns, it should help you deal with your own problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Projects.Project
  , [Open]   = count(case when tasks.status='open' then 1 end)
  , Canceled = count(case when tasks.status='Canceled ' then 1 end)
  , Rejected = count(case when tasks.status='Rejected ' then 1 end)
  , Total = COUNT(Tasks.Status)
FROM
  Projects
  LEFT JOIN Tasks ON Projects.ID = Tasks.ProjectID
 GROUP BY
   Projects.Project
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b862/4/0

returns:

```
+----------+------+----------+----------+-------+
| Project  | Open | Canceled | Rejected | Total |
+----------+------+----------+----------+-------+
| Accounts |    0 |        2 |        1 |     3 |
| Admin    |    1 |        3 |        0 |     4 |
| Finance  |    0 |        4 |        1 |     5 |
+----------+------+----------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT
      Projects.Project,
      Tasks.Status
    FROM
      Projects
      LEFT JOIN Tasks ON Projects.ID = Tasks.ProjectID
) Src 
    PIVOT (COUNT(Status) FOR Status IN ([Open] ,[Canceled],[Rejected])) P
```

Result:

```
Project    Open        Canceled    Rejected
---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Accounts   0           2           1
Admin      1           3           0
Finance    0           4           1
```